# jQuery not getting value from JSON key

Tags: jquery, json

I have a really small jquery program that is trying to get the the value fom a key. The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "Key1": [
        "http://a.com",
        "http: //b.com",
        "http://c.net"
    ],
    "Key2": [
        "http://a.com",
        "http: //b.com",
        "http://c.net"
    ],
    "Key3": [
        "http://a.com",
        "http: //b.com",
        "http://c.net"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the value of one by the key. Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('url_dict.json', function(json) {         
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
           if (key == "Key1") {
            console.log(key.value);
           } else {
            console.log("Nope");
           };
        });
});
```

All I ever get is Nope. If I change it to key, value, they print it out fine. I only have an issue if I try to drill down by key.

Comment: When i try it i do not always get Nope, i get undefined and nope. Your key's don't have value properties (they're strings!). http://jsfiddle.net/m3gfx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code. The variable value is an array, so you need to loop over it to get each item.

```
$.getJSON('url_dict.json', function(json) {         
  $.each(json, function(key, value) {
       if (key == "Key1") {
        $.each(value, function(k, v) {
            console.log(v);
        });
       } else {
        console.log("Nope");
       };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be *looping the array*.

### Updates:

Here the point that you have to a look is

```
key1 //is a string
[ "http://a.com", "http: //b.com", "http://c.net"] // an array
```

*Hence iterate the value not the key*

```
if (key == "Key1") {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            console.log(value[i]);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Nope");
    };
```

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/m3gfx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

key.value is actually coming out 'undefined', followed by two 'Nope's

You can get the array out of Key1 like this:

```
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
   if (key == 'Key1') {
    console.log(value);  //or value[0] will give you: http://a.com
   } else {
    console.log("Nope");
   };
});
```

Comment: Could I get this to return the array outside of the function, passs it to a var? Could I assign a global like var ulrs = value(); then return urls; ?